Inserting navigation with jquery doesn't render HTML when view page source
I have a static HTML website and I would like to inject the navigation for each page using jquery. I cannot use PHP as it has to be static site (HTML, CSS, JS). The injected navigation displays fine and is there when I do "inspect element" however when I check "page source" code the navigation is not there rendered but I see only jquery script that is supposed to inject the navigation? Is this correct? As I think this is the problem why some of my other js code doesn't work as the navigation is not fully rendered?
Here is the HTML code of my website:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-147159589-1"></script>
  <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-147159589-1');
  </script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Wynajmij magiczny dom w lesie z kameralnym dostępem do jeziora, sauną, kominkiem. Pozbądź się ograniczeń, zyskaj niepowtarzalną energię wprost z natury. Uwolnij się od wielkomiejskiego pędu. Pobudź swoją kreatywność.">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Domek nad jeziorem. Ukryj Się w głuszy. Dom otulony lasem i jeziorem.</title>
    
  <!-- hreflang-implementation -->
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl"
        href="https://ukryjsie.pl/" />    
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en"
        href="https://ukryjsie.pl/en" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default"
        href="https://ukryjsie.pl/en" />

  <!-- OpenGraph tags-->
  <meta property="og:title" content="Domek nad jeziorem. Ukryj się w głuszy. Domek otulony lasem i jeziorem." />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Wynajmij magiczny dom w lesie z kameralnym dostępem do jeziora, sauną, kominkiem. Pozbądź się ograniczeń, zyskaj niepowtarzalną energię wprost z natury. Uwolnij się od wielkomiejskiego pędu. Pobudź swoją kreatywność." />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://ukryjsie.pl/img/domek-w-lesie-taras-okno-noc.jpg" />
    
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-icons/1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" integrity="sha512-dPXYcDub/aeb08c63jRq/k6GaKccl256JQy/AnOq7CAnEZ9FzSL9wSbcZkMp4R26vBsMLFYH4kQ67/bbV8XaCQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">-->

  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/grayscale.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/grayscale-overwrite.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
  <!-- Scripts -->    
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    
  <!-- Favicon -->  
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    
  <!-- Mailchimp waiting list on exit pop-up -->
  <script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/d3171834443fe13e001642aa4/0ed3113275e58a0cb957fa0de.js");</script>
    
  <!-- BEGIN scripts-header.php INCLUDE -->
  <?php include "./php-include/scripts-header.php"; ?>
  <!-- END scripts-header.php INCLUDE -->
    
    <meta name="facebook-domain-verification" content="bkmr11g3sjg8ohzxc8epiycr8fuf5r" />
    
</head>

<body id="page-top">

    
<div id="navigation"></div>
    
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#navigation").load("nav.html");
});
</script>
    
    

<!-- BEGIN nav.php INCLUDE -->
<!--    <?php include "./php-include/nav.php"; ?>-->
<!-- END nav.php INCLUDE -->

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="masthead" title="Domek nad jeziorem z tarasem">
    <div class="container d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
      <div class="mx-auto text-center">
        <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">Ukryj Się</h1>
        <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5">Twój domek nad jeziorem</h2>
        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">O co chodzi?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- About Section -->
  <section id="about" class="about-section text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-full">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2 class="text-white mb-4">Lekarstwo na współczesność</h2>
          <p class="text-white-50">Zbudowaliśmy domek nad jeziorem, otulony lasem, wypełniony ciepłem i pozytywną energią. Natura, sauna, kominek, cisza i spokój...czego chcieć więcej?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Projects Section -->
  <section id="projects" class="projects-section bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Featured Project Row -->
      <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7">
          <img class="img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="img/domek-w-lesie-trzcina-taras.jpg" alt="Dom w lesie nad jeziorem">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5">
          <div class="featured-text text-center text-lg-left">
            <h4>To nie jest hotel</h4>
            <p class="text-black-50 mb-0">Przytulna kryjówka. Dziewicza natura. Specjalnie dla Ciebie.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Project One Row -->
      <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters mb-5 mb-lg-0">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/domek-w-lesie-salon-kominek.jpg" alt="Domek w lesie salon i kominek">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="bg-black text-center h-100 project">
            <div class="d-flex h-100">
              <div class="project-text w-100 my-auto text-center text-lg-left">
                <h4 class="text-white">Bez kłopotów</h4>
                <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">
Nasz domek nad jeziorem jest godzinę drogi od Poznania, w stronę Warszawy. Wystarczająco daleko, aby się odłączyć. Na tyle blisko, by nie spędzać długich godzin w podróży.</p>
                <hr class="d-none d-lg-block mb-0 ml-0">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Project Two Row -->
      <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/domek-w-lesie-taras-lampion-po-zachodzie.jpg" alt="Domek w lesie nocą i lampion">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-first">
          <div class="bg-black text-center h-100 project">
            <div class="d-flex h-100">
              <div class="project-text w-100 my-auto text-center text-lg-right">
                <h4 class="text-white">Obsesyjnie zaprojektowany</h4>
                <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">
By czuć się częścią krajobrazu. Być w naturze. Nie obok niej.</p>
                <hr class="d-none d-lg-block mb-0 mr-0">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
    
  <!-- Big image section -->
  <section class="bigimage-section" title="Kobieta w czerwonej sukience, siedząca na przewróconym drzewie w lesie o zachodzie słońca.">
    
  </section>
    
    <!-- Why reasons -->
<div class="container">

  <!-- Page Heading -->
  <h2 class="custom-heading">Po co to wszystko?
  </h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="img/domek-w-lesie-taras-hamak.jpg" alt="Domek w lesie hamak i książka"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">Skup się</a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text">Pozbądź się ograniczeń. Wejdź na zupełnie nowy poziom kreatywności i wydajności - napędzany przez naturę.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="img/kobiety-las-kamping-smiech.jpg" alt="Śmiejące się kobiety siedzą na trawie w lesie i piją herbatę podgrzaną na gazie"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">Doświadczaj</a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text">Urokliwe jezioro, las, relaks w saunie, kominek. To wszystko na wyłączność.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="img/domek-w-lesie-sypialnia.jpg" alt="Sypialnia domku z dużym oknem z widokiem na las"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">Kryjówka</a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text">Pośpiech, przepracowanie. To Twój wybór. Powiedz nie. Wypocznij z dala od zgiełku. Zwolnij z nami. To działa.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->

</div>
<!-- /.container -->



<!-- Signup Section -->
  <section id="signup" class="signup-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 mx-auto text-center">

          <i class="far fa-paper-plane fa-2x mb-2 text-white"></i>
          <h2 class="text-white mb-5">Do dzieła! Dobre terminy szybko sie kończą...</h2>
          <a href="/rezerwuj" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Rezerwuj Domek Nad Jeziorem</a>

          <!-- Signup Form
          <form class="form-inline d-flex" action="https://gmail.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="u" value="d3171834443fe13e001642aa4">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4f37811df8">
              
          <input type="email" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" class="form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Wpisz adres email...">
          //real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or //risk form bot signups
          <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_d3171834443fe13e001642aa4_4f37811df8" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Dołącz</button>
          </form>
          -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Contact Section -->
  <section class="contact-section bg-black">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <div class="card py-4 h-100">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt text-primary mb-2"></i>
              <h4 class="text-uppercase m-0">Adres</h4>
              <hr class="my-4">
              <div class="small text-black-50">Smolniki Powidzkie, woj. wielkopolskie. Sprawdź <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/2mefoKUrrWsd5hjz8" target="_blank">lokalizację domku na Google Mapie</a>.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <div class="card py-4 h-100">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope text-primary mb-2"></i>
              <h4 class="text-uppercase m-0">Email</h4>
              <hr class="my-4">
              <div class="small text-black-50">
                <a href="mailto:justyna.idzkowska@gmail.com?subject=Domek%20nad%20jeziorem">justyna.idzkowska@gmail.com</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <div class="card py-4 h-100">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt text-primary mb-2"></i>
              <h4 class="text-uppercase m-0">Telefon</h4>
              <hr class="my-4">
              <div class="small text-black-50">+48 508 165 685</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        
        <!-- Social-->
      <div class="social d-flex justify-content-center">
        <!--<a href="#" class="mx-2">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>-->
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ukryjsiepl" target="_blank" class="mx-2">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ukryjsie/" target="_blank" class="mx-2">
          <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
        </a>
        <!--<a href="#" class="mx-2">
          <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
        </a>-->
      </div>
        

<div class="container">
<h3 style="margin-top: 95px; color:#ffffff80;">Przydatne informacje</h3>
    <hr class="d-none d-lg-block mb-0 ml-0">
  <div style="text-align: left; color:#ffffff80; margin-top: 50px;" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Domki nad jeziorem i w lesie</strong></p><p>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/domek-nad-jeziorem">Domek nad jeziorem</a> <br>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/dom-nad-jeziorem">Dom nad jeziorem</a><br>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/domek-w-lesie">Domek w lesie</a><br></p>
       
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Lokalizacja domków</strong></p><p>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="https://goo.gl/maps/2mefoKUrrWsd5hjz8" target="_blank">Domek nad jeziorem</a><br>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="https://goo.gl/maps/hcS4qpha1iAsNFcT8" target="_blank">Domek w lesie</a><br></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Zajrzyj na naszego bloga</strong></p><p>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/wakacje-z-psem">Wakacje z psem</a> <br>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/wakacje-w-dubaju-subiektywny-przewodnik">Wakacje w Dubaju</a><br>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/slot-art-festival">Slot Art Festival</a><br>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/wakacje-pod-namiotem-kemping-w-chorwacji">Kemping w Chorwacji</a><br>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/domek-nad-jeziorem-atrakcje-wielkopolska">Atrakcje w domku nad jeziorem</a><br>
        <a style="color:#ffffff80;" href="/jak-zbudowac-saune-poradnik">Jak zbudować saunę - poradnik</a><br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="bg-black small text-center text-white-50">
          <p class="copyright">
<!--          <a style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);" href="/lista-rezerwowa" style>Nie znalazłeś wolnego terminu?</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);" href="/domki-lesne">Sprawdź nasze pozostałe domki w lesie</a></p>-->
          <a style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);" href="/lista-rezerwowa" style>Nie znalazłeś wolnego terminu?</a></p>
          <p class="copyright"><a style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);" href="/polityka-prywatnosci" style>Polityka Prywatności</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);" href="/polityka-cookies">Polityka Cookies</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);" href="/regulamin">Regulamin</a></p>
          <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; Ukryj Się <script>$('#spanYear').html(new Date().getFullYear());</script></p>
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="js/grayscale.min.js"></script>
    
  <!-- BEGIN scripts.php INCLUDE -->
<!--        <?php include "./php-include/scripts.php"; ?>-->
  <!-- END scripts.php INCLUDE -->

</body>

</html>



And the jquery navigation bit:


<script>
$(function() {
    $("#navigation").load("nav.html");
});
</script>



And the HTML navigation:


<!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Ukryj Się</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/domek-nad-jeziorem">Domek nad jeziorem</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/dom-nad-jeziorem">Dom nad jeziorem</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/domek-w-lesie">Domek w lesie</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/opinie">Opinie</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/cennik">Cennik</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/rezerwuj">Rezerwuj</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger nav-item-desktop-hide" href="/podaruj-pobyt">Vouchery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/blog">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#signup">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/en">&#127468;&#127463;</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>



The question is how to render the navigation fully so it can be targeted by js code without problems?

You mean to say : $("#navigation").load("nav.html"); code doesn't load the full navigation?
